# Angular JS Controller not rendering table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I am stuck on a problem.
I want to take first and last names as Input show them as full names and add them separately on a table by push method. Full name function is working properly but another controller is either not working or showing the results.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-KZmyTq3PLx9EZl0RHShHQuXtrvdJ+m35tuOiwlcZfs/rE7NZv29ygNA8SFCkMXTnYZQK2OX0Gm2qKGfvWEtRXA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="addRow()">
      First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="firstName"><br>
      Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lastName"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
    <p> Full Name: {{fullName()}}</p>
    <div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
          <td>{{x.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{x.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.firstName = myForm.fname.value;
      $scope.lastName = myForm.lname.value;
      $scope.fullName = function () {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
      };
    });
    app.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.records = [];
      $scope.addRow = function () {
        $scope.records.push({
          'firstName': $scope.firstName,
          'lastName': $scope.lastName
        });
      };
    }]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code of the index.html file I am using Angular js with a CDN link.

Comment: addRow function is used outside the tableCtrl - so is unknown. Put addRow function and list of records into myCtrl, to make it work. Then you do not need tableCtrl, exept if you want to add additional logic (delete row).

Comment: @AvgustinTomsic It worked, thank you. but it was not showing the full name so I had to define the full name function in the tableCtrl controller instead. Thank you!